# Parent class for two enum subclasses?

Tags: inheritance, java-8, enums

I have found two almost indentical enums in my code and I would like to extract it's common methods to the parent class - but enum cannot inherit from each other so is there some elegant workaround for this problem so EnumA and EnumB could have the same method implementation in their parent?

Comment: `enum` types can implement interfaces and interfaces can have `default` methods, which works as long as you can settle those common operations atop other methods implemented by the concrete `enum` types. It’s not possible to say more, without additional information.

Comment: Hi, Could you please provide more information about enums and common operations?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my answer is based upon the suggestion from Holger in comments. It's possible for enums to implement a common interface and have common logic shared via the interface. Let's take an example. Consider two enums `Planet` and `Satellite`. Both enums are similar which have mass and radius attributes. I introduced an interface called `CelestialBody` which contains the logic for calculating Surface gravity and Surface weight:

```java
public interface CelestialBody {
    double G = 6.67300E-11;

    default double surfaceGravity(double mass, double radius) {
        return G * mass / (radius * radius);
    }

    default double surfaceWeight(double otherMass, double mass, double radius) {
        return otherMass * surfaceGravity(mass, radius);
    }
}
```

Both `Planet` and `Satellite` enums would be implementing this interface and would have access to  `surfaceWeight()` and `surfaceGravity()` methods. Note that I've added `surfaceGravity()` methods in enums just to make methods look cleaner. They are just wrappers delegating calculation to method in parent interface:

Planet Enum:

```java
public enum Planet implements CelestialBody {
    MERCURY (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
    VENUS   (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
    EARTH   (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
    MARS    (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
    JUPITER (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7),
    SATURN  (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
    URANUS  (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
    NEPTUNE (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

    private final double mass;
    private final double radius;

    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

   /**
     * Wrapper around CelestialBody.surfaceGravity() delegates Surface gravity
     * related calculation to implementation in parent interface
     * 
     * @return double value for Surface Gravity
     */
    public double surfaceGravity() {
        return surfaceGravity(mass, radius);
    }
}
```

Satellite Enum:

```java
public enum Satellites implements CelestialBody {
    CALLISTO(1.07593e+23, 2.410e+3),
    MOON(7.34767309e+22, 1.7371e+3),
    EUROPA(4.79984e+22, 1.5608e+3),
    DIONE(1.095552e+21,5.614e+2);

    private final double mass;
    private final double radius;

    Satellites(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

   /**
     * Wrapper around CelestialBody.surfaceGravity() delegates Surface gravity
     * related calculation to implementation in parent interface
     * 
     * @return double value for Surface Gravity
     */
    public double surfaceGravity() {
        return surfaceGravity(mass, radius);
    }
}
```

You should be able to access these methods. I tested it with this code:

```java
System.out.println("Moon's surface gravity: " + Satellites.MOON.surfaceGravity());
System.out.println("Mars's surface gravity: " + Planet.MARS.surfaceGravity());
System.out.println("Jupiter's surface gravity: " + Planet.JUPITER.surfaceGravity());
```

It prints the following output:

```
Moon's surface gravity: 1624880.0625269841
Mars's surface gravity: 3.7126290961053403
Jupiter's surface gravity: 24.80617666947324
```